# How can I close a child window with WM_CLOSE?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, hwnd

I create the child `hwnd` as popup with close button and `WndchildProc` for handle message from child window

```
m_childHwnd = CreateWindowEx(
NULL, 
TEXT("STATIC"), TEXT("childW"), 
WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_VISIBLE, 
CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
 m_parentHWnd, NULL, 
GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL
);

m_childhProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(m_childHwnd , GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)WndChildProc);

static LRESULT CALLBACK WndChildProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, 
LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (message)
{
case WM_CLOSE:
    DestroyWindow(hwnd);
return 0;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
}
default:
    return CallWindowProc(m_childhProc, hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I expected when I press close button of child window the message `WM_CLOSE` will trigger. And I can close child `hwnd` with this way.

But when close button of child `hwnd` pressed, nothing happen. If close button of `parent-hwnd` pressed, `WM_DESTROY` message trigger.
So, I can't close (just) the child window with its close button.

How can I close a child window with its close button?

Updated: missing text in copying, added: CallWindowProc for default case.

Comment: Your window procedure needs to call the default window procedure for all the other cases.

Comment: A child window is a window with the `WS_CHILD` style. There is none in your question. I'm not following, what problem you are trying to solve. Besides, it's time to ditch the old (and dangerous) way to subclass controls, and go with the provided infrastructure instead (see [Subclassing Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

I found solution with event WM_NCLBUTTONUP trigger when close button clicked.

```
case WM_NCLBUTTONUP:
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);
    return 0;
```